# Why "Questions needs votes too." is displayed so shortly?

Tags: discussion, bug, error-message

Popup with message "*You haven't voted on a question in a while. Questions need votes too.*" is displayed so shortly and dissapears so quickly, that I managed to read and understand, what it says, after about fifth attempt or so. Though, I think, my English is quite good.

People with worse understanding of English simply won't read / understand, what this message is saying.

If I'm not mistaken, this popup uses the same mechanism as the one used to display "*Thanks, we'll take a look at it*". But -- if, again, I'm not mistaken, the second one is displayed noticeable longer.

It there any reason, why this -- kind important -- message, telling people, that they should vote also on question, is displayed so shortly?